# Set app activity to accept action.VIEW action

Tags: android, android-activity

When user tap on button this code is happen:

```
Uri web = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,web);
startActivity(i);
```

And it's runs OK, open website in default web browser. But I am trying to display the menu, that appears if you have more applications capable to display web pages installed.
So I prepared blank application FakeBrowser with this AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pavel.fakebrowser" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="google.com"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I try to set the second intent-filter tag, so my app will be accept this browser request, but it's still immediately opens default browser.
Please can you tell me, what I have wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an IntentChooser:

```
Uri web = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,web);
startActivity( Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose Application"));
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

UPDATE:
And on your manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes, this part was missing. But result is still same. When I click button, without any choosing dialog, page is opened in default browser.
So I still have some mistake in AndroidManifest.Xml of FakeBrowser app?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Let me know if it works for you